# Applications requiring internet access crash

Tags: networking, internet

i have loaded Ubuntu desktop, studio, server, mint. I know I have a good internet connection because I get the latest packages during the install, but as soon as I try to run Mozilla or any program that uses the internet the program crashes.

- My network card is OK because i can see my intranet. I am also seeing my USB ports tend to come and go front to back erratically. please help i am trying to setup a Linux PC for my wife.
- I have heard that running graphical programs as root will mess up
  your profile; so i created a user account and get the same results.
  **Firefox, Thunderbird and all programs that need internet access crash.** I have sent crash reports but have not got a response yet. i
  have a valid DHCP assigned IP address that I can ping on the
  intranet.

Comment: I understand that you feel it's happening with most programs.  But it's very important for you to include a specific program and specific error outputs.  If we are able to resolve the problem with a specific program, it might resolve problems with other of programs you are having issues with.  Since you mentioned Firefox.  Will you run it from the terminal and provide us with the console errors that happens when it crashes.  As far as running as Root, sudden, the corruption might already be done.  It might have to be fixed for you to be able to run as a non-root user.

Comment: We need to know more to understand what's happening. Please also add information whether it is laptop computer or desktop, which PC model and network cards etc.